# AngularJS "debounce" for ngBind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind

For ngModel there is a ngModelOptions such as 
`ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"`

Is there something similar for ngBind or `{{}}` ?

Basically, I am binding some data to a div element using `ng-bind` and as the default behavior of Angular.js, data gets updated on the div element as soon as it is updated in the model. I want to delay this updation or data binding on the div whenever the data changes in the model. Such that when the data is changed in the model ($scope) this change should appear only after say, 2 seconds on the div element. How to make this work?

Comment: You could use $scope.$watch for this, but I'm curious as to your use case. I don't see why you would want to delay the update of the view rather than the update of the model.

Comment: @DanPantry, Can you please give an example, how to achieve this using $watch?

Comment: Actually - nvm - I don't think you can :S

Comment: Could you give an example of your use case? There may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I think I might have solved the problem. Thanks to the clue that you gave me. I tried delaying the model update and it appears to be working now. let me check if it has any impact elsewhere. Thanks @DanPantry . :)

Comment: `ng-model-options` delays the model update, so if this is your solution, why would you do something else? Unless I am misunderstanding. Please elaborate in a self-answer at least.

Comment: No, `ng-model-options` is not the answer, as far as I tried, it only works on form elements like an input text box.

Comment: Well, yes, that is how model binding works - models can only be supplied on input elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. I was thinking in terms of updating the view, but as suggested by @DanPantry, I tried delaying the value/model updation using a timeout because of which the value got updated some milliseconds later and the rest was taken care by the angular.js `$digest` cycles. :)

For example I did something like the following:

```
$timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                $rootScope.current.index = idx;
            });
        }, 100);
```